# What is the right way to build an entity with relationships

Tags: spring, architecture, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I have some factory that's responsible to build `Product` entity. To build the `Product` it's necessary to retrieve all entities from a data source that should be associated with `Product`.

```
class ProductFactory(
    private val productRepository: ProductRepository,
    private val shopRepository: ShopRepository,
    private val categoryRepository: CategoryRepository,
    private val tagRepository: TagRepository
) {
    fun build(action: CreateProductDTO): Product {
         val product = Product.Builder()
         val shop = shopRepository.findById(action.shopId)
         product.setShop(shop)

         val tags = tagRepository.findAllById(action.tags)
         product.setTags(tags)

         val category = categoryRepository.findById(action.categoryId)
         product.setTaxon(taxon)

         return productRepository.save(builder.build())
    }
}
```

Personally I don't like the code above because of interface segregation principle violation at least. `ProductFactory` can access to all methods of the repositories but should not supposed to do this.

I have a thought to create some kind of DAL called `Storage` that could be used for specific business operation such as product creation. For example:

```
interface Storage {
    fun findShopById(id: Long): Optional<Shop>
    fun findCategoryById(id: Long): Optional<Category>
    fun findAllTagsById(ids: Iterable<Long>): List<Tag>
    fun save(product: Product)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface segregation principle that you want to apply is a good idea. It makes testing much easier, because you only need one mock and and not a whole bunch of mocks.

I would name the interface after the client that it is dedicated to, e.g. `ProductFactoryRepository`.

The code that your `ProductRepository` implements seems to be code that I usually would write in an interactor (aka. use case). Of cource you can extract it to an own class if you want.

But there is one thing that might break the architecture (if I understand your code). It is this function.

```
 fun build(action: CreateProductDTO): Product {
```

As far as I understand you. The `ProductFactory` is part of the entity (or domain) layer. The `CreateProductDTO` seems to belong to the controller (web or transport) layer, because DTO usually stands for data *transfer* object.

But this would mean that you have a dependency from the entity layer to the transport layer, which breaks the architecture rules of the clean architecture.

The clean architecture proposes to pass plain data structures into an `InputPort`. These data structures are often called `RequestModel` and `ResponseModel`.

The interactor should implement an input port such as this:

```
interface CreateProductInputPort {
    fun createProduct(requestModel: CreateProductRequestModel, outputPort: CreateProductOutputPort)
}
```

The `RequestModel` can either be a simple data like

```
data class CreateProductRequestModel(val shopId: Int, val tags: Array<String>, val categoryId: Int)
```

or you can declare an interface

```
interface CreateProductRequestModel {
   fun getShopId(): Int
   fun getTags(): Array<String>
   fun getCategoryId(): Int
}
```

and let `CreateProductDTO` implement it.

You should decouple the interactor (use case) from the transport layer in order to apply the single responsibility principle, because the DTO changes for other reasons than the use cases input model.

PS: I hope the Kotlin code I wrote is correct. I usually code in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *instantiation* and *insertion* concepts here:

- *Insertion* is a logical operation which happens when you add a new entity into your system, like adding a new product to the product catalog.
- *Instantiation* is a technical operation which happens when you want to create a new object in memory, like when you convert a DTO into an entity, or you whant to retrieve an existing product from the database.

In DDD, a *factory* is an object responsible for an entity *instantiation*. Entity *insertion* is the responsibility of the *repository*. Most of the time, you don't need to write a factory because you can write some simple code like `Product product = new Product();` or use some mapping library to project a data persistence object (DPO) into an entity.

Sometimes though, object instantiation can become a complex task, and you can write a factory to factor this code and reuse it from different classes. Instead of writing `Product product = new Product();` you would write something like `Product product = productFactory.MakeProduct(...);` and inject the factory.

This means your `ProductFactory` should actually be your `Builder` class:

```
class ProductRepository(
    private val productFactory: ProductFactory,
    private val shopRepository: ShopRepository,
    private val categoryRepository: CategoryRepository,
    private val tagRepository: TagRepository
) {
    fun insert(action: CreateProductDTO): Product {
         val shop = shopRepository.findById(action.shopId)
         val tags = tagRepository.findAllById(action.tags)
         val category = categoryRepository.findById(action.categoryId)
         val product = productFactory.MakeProduct(shop, tags, category)
         product.Name = action.productName
         return this.save(product)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the DDD dogma, two aggregates should refer each other using ids, not setting the entire Shop/Tag/Category inside the Product aggregate :) that's why that code feels odd to you, breaking that rule create the necessity for using the repositories at all.

Using the entire `Shop` is driven by the technology you are using for persistence, I suppose.
What you are interested in doing in the factory is checking if a store with that id actually exists or not.

That should be handled executing a query (passing a service) to your `ProductFactory` so that it will be decoupled from the details of the `Shop` and can access only API that exposed by your domain (through the service query/commands)